# How do I hide a bootstrap-select?

Tags: css, bootstrap-select

I need to hide a select statement for part of an web application. At one point in the code I say $("#select1").addClass("hidden"); to hide it. Until I decided to use bootstrap-select it worked fine. But since I added the class="selectpicker" it no longer hides when told to. 
I can see the 'hidden' has been added to the class statement using web inspector but the select is not actually hidden. How do I make this work?

Comment: An example illustrating the issue using site like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) will help people answer your question. What about `hide` class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**bootstrap-select** convert your **select** tag to a list of buttons. You should `hide` or `show` its parent instead of itself to avoid css override.
Example:

```
<div class="form-group" id="form-group-1">
  <label for="select1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="select1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button id="btn-hide">Hide select</button>
<button id="btn-show">Show select</button>
```

In this case we will hide or show `#form-group-1` instead of `#select1`:

```
$("#btn-hide").click(function(){
  $("#form-group-1").hide();
});

$("#btn-show").click(function(){
  $("#form-group-1").show();
});
```

Please take a look at my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33638/).

Comment: I notice that the <label for="select1">Select list:</label> does not hide however. Thoughts?

Comment: label inside `<div class="form-group" id="form-group-1">` should be hidden if we hide parent div. I think you should share a working JSFiddle with your code.

Answer (score 5):

You can also try

```
  <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="your_id">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
  </select>
```

and to hide or show use

```
$('#your_id').selectpicker('hide');
$('#your_id').selectpicker('show');
```